# How to read and manipulate xls file in c#

Tags: c#

I am working on application that needs a xls file to be read.
Here we can add a new row to excel file or delete some rows from excel files.

How can i achieve this in C#

Comment: I had finished writing your code for you, but then all of a sudden I thought "Heyyyy, wait a frikkin minute!"

Comment: I thinks some of the moderators on this site become habitual of putting nagetive votes on questions. This site is for helping those who needs some help out of you not just getting nagetive votes from you.

Answer (score 2):

```
try Aspose components they have lot of interactive operations with Excel
```

[also try this](http://www.aspose.com/demos/.net-components/aspose.cells/csharp/quick-start/rows-and-columns/default.aspx)